# Remove the coefficients from a SymPy expression

Tags: python, sympy

I have a symbolic expression in SymPy that I need to remove all the coefficients from after I take the 2nd derivative of the expression.  Here is the code

```
import sympy as sym

x, y = sym.symbols('x y')

# define the shape function 
S_function =                0                                 +\
                         x + y                                +\
                   x**2 + x*y + y**2                          +\
             x**3 + x**2*y + x*y**2 + y**3                   

# take the 2nd derivative of the shape function for the x components
S_function_xx = sym.expand(sym.diff(S_function,x,2))

print(S_function_xx)
```

And I get an output of 6*x + 2*y + 2, I need to convert this to x + y. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Correct, I have removed the term leading.  I simply want to remove the coefficients form the expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the expression is in fact a polynomial (as here), the following can be used: convert it to a [Poly object](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html), get its list of monomials with `monoms`, then recombine, deleting the constant term.

```
monom_list = sym.Poly(S_function_xx, x, y).monoms()
new_function = sum([x**a*y**b for a, b in monom_list if a + b > 0])
```

If `S_function_xx` is not a polynomial, it's not so clear what is a "coefficient".

Comment: Yes, I should have treated it as a polynomial from the start.  I do not understand SymPy as well I would like to.